# Unable to parse org.apache.avro.util.Utf8 to java.time.ZonedDateTime

Tags: parsing, avro, zoneddatetime

I have tried below tests. But unable to parse the date format: `2020-04-19T19:00:54`

why am I facing this issue?

```
public ZonedDateTime convert(Utf8 date) {
    String datee = ((String) date.toString()).replace("T", " ")
    LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.parse(datee, formatter)  
    ZonedDateTime currentISTime = today.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    ZonedDateTime currentETime = currentISTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(formatter.format(currentETime), formatter) 
}

String datee = ((String) date.toString()).replace("T", " ")  
try{
    var zoned = ZonedDateTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse(datee.toString()))
    return zoned.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault())
} catch (DateTimeException e) {
    //no time zone information -> parse as LocalDate
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(datee.toString())
}
```

Exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-04-19 19:00:54' could not be parsed at index 10 at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
    at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:598)
    at java.base/java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:583)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your Date-Time string

You do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse your Date-Time string because your Date-Time string is already in ISO 8601 format.

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-04-19T19:00:54";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(ldt);

        // Convert to ZonedDateTime using JVM's timezone
        ZonedDateTime zdtSystem = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdtSystem);

        // Convert the ZonedDateTime to some other timezone e.g. Asia/Kolkata
        ZonedDateTime zdtIndia = zdtSystem.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
        System.out.println(zdtIndia);
    }
}
```

**Output on my system in Europe/London timezone:**

```
2020-04-19T19:00:54
2020-04-19T19:00:54+01:00[Europe/London]
2020-04-19T23:30:54+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/6QDxKv)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>